# Unable to fetch text from textarea via Robot Framework

Tags: textarea, robotframework

I am trying to fetch text ( eg abc ) from text area over an application . The tag text area in the source code doesn't contain abc though it is visible on the screen and I want to capture it  .

I have tried `Get Text` keyword of Robot Framework yet my returned value is empty. I would need to understand what more can I use to get the text area value .

```
${ExceptionValue} =  Get Text xpath=//textarea[contains(text(),'abc')]
```

Expected result is `${ExceptionValue}` value should not be empty as there is text in the text area . Yet the value returned is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The entered text in a `<textarea>` is actually stored in its property `value`, it's not a part of its text. You can see that by typing something, and then opening it through "Inspect Element" in the browser - as you said, you can see the typed text in the page, but it is not between the opening and closing tags in the HTML source.

Thus the keyword `Get Text` returned an empty string to you - it works with the content between those opening and closing tags. To get the actual value - what you did type, get the value of the property `value`, and for that - use the keyword [`Get Element Attribute`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) :

```
${my typed text}=   Get Element Attribute    locator_for_the_element    value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get Value` keyword instead. Get Text is only applicable if the text is visible in source page or DOM. Try the following.

```
${ExceptionValue} = Get Value xpath=//textarea[contains(text(),'abc')]
```

Please let me know if this solve the problem.

Comment: Hi , tried with Get value earlier , it  was not fetching the value . Like i said the value is not visible in the <testarea> tag yet it is present on the screen . So neither get value nor get text is helping . It similar to this problem statement - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-devel/VGlUhxInHi8